# Is there a way to run a bat file whenever network connected?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I want to automatically pass the firewall whenever the network connected (WIFI and LAN), I have a bat file to do this, but every time I need to run it manually, so is there a way to run this bat file whenever network available?
Expect that there is a event listener for network status that I can hook to run the bat file.
Or scheduled tasks can do this job?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing this would be to ping the lan until it becomes available

```
:LOOP
ping 192.168.x.x | find "Reply" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 start yourbatchfile && exit /b >nul
timeout /t 5
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution of monitor it all the time, I'm trying to find a way of listener to solve this problem.